# Confusing regarding .get and .set in an ArrayList

Tags: java

(I'm new at Java, coming over from Python ---)

I'm going through a tutorial and they've created a program which counts how many times a number appears in a file, then returns that number.  One particular part of the program is somewhat mysterious to me and deals with the ArrayList's .get and .set (methods? functions?).  The program goes like this:

```
//  (Scan a file with the numbers, say, 2 2 3 4, and put it into data1 variable.)
//  (Make An Empty ArrayList with a bunch of 0's)

Scanner data1 = null;
ArrayList<Integer> count = new ArrayList<Integer>();
Integer idx;

while(data1.hasNextInt()){
  idx = data1.nextInt();
  System.out.println(idx);
  System.out.println(count.get(idx)+1);
  count.set(idx,count.get(idx)+1);
}

//Then prints out all the values; the ArrayList contains the number of times the number n occurs in the n-th index.
```

My question comes at the "while" part.  For concrete, let's assume data1 has the numbers 2 2 3 4.  It seems that it takes idx = 2, then puts a 1 in count[2], which is reasonable.  It then takes idx = 2 again (the next integer in data1) and puts a 2 in count[2], which is also reasonable.  *At this point*, the next number in data1 makes idx = 3, but it occurs at the index 2 in the ArrayList, so it should put a 3 in count[3], which is incorrect.

So, what is .get and .set doing here?  Do they pop the elements off of the list when they're done with it?  Am I overlooking something?

Comment: fixed your intendation and syntax a bit - java uses C-Style comments (`//` single, `/* ... */` multi line).

Comment: This code will not compile, the `count` list has not been initialized; or is it in the `//  (Make An Empty ArrayList with a bunch of 0's)` part? If yes, can you add that?

Comment: @james and I've fixed the initialization of the list.

Comment: I've made a ton of mistakes on this pseudocode.  Yes, I'm sorry, that should be up there.

Comment: Also, note that, like I say in my answer, lists are not "automagically" filled. How are the 0s filled? How many of them are there?

Comment: Why should it put 3 in count[3]? It will put 1 in count[3] (given that the ArrayList is big enough and initialzed with zeros).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `.get()` will not automagically get elements from a `List` which does not have that many elements. Note: list indices, like arrays, start at 0.

If you do:

```
final List<Integer> = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.get(0);
```

this is a runtime error (`IndexOutOfBoundsException`) because your list has no elements.

You have to fill it:

```
list.add(1); // append an element
list.get(0); // returns element at index 0
list.get(1); // IndexOutOfBoundsException!
```

The `.set()` method takes an index and a value at an argument. In a similar vein, you cannot set an element which does not already exist, except at the very end of the list:

```
// start from an empty list
list.set(1, 32); // IndexOutOfBoundsException!
list.set(0, 32); // OK
```

Final note: try not to use `list[i]`, bracket indices are used for arrays ;) Note that arrays are *not* resizabe in Java. `List`s (which are an implementation of a `Collection`), however, are. But you must append to them.

So, what this line does:

```
count.set(idx, count.get(idx) + 1);
```

is take the value at index `idx`, add 1 to it, and sets back this value at the same index.

Comment: !!  Okay, that last part was exactly what I needed.  I thought that it added 1 to the *index*, instead of adding 1 to the actual value at that place.  It was a silly mistake on my part.  Thank you!

Comment: I am curious to see however the initialization of the list by your sample... And yeah, Java has `Map`, which is sort of like a python dict -- except its keys can be anything, even `Map`s... But that is another story ;) Hint: read the javadoc for `Object` and in particular `.equals()` and `.hashCode()`.

Answer (score 0):

You are currently using an `ArrayList`, which acts like an array, but makes it easier to expand it - for example, add elements to it.

What you want is the java equivalent of the python `dict`, a key/value storage, in java, this is called a `HashMap<K,V>` ([docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)).

```
Scanner data1 = null;
HashMap<Integer, Integer> count = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
Integer idx;

while(data1.hasNextInt()) {
  idx = data1.nextInt();
  System.out.println(idx);
  Integer g = count.get(idx)+1;

  if(g == null) {
    g = 0;
  }
  g++;
  System.out.println(g);
  count.put(idx, g);
}
```

Comment: You must control for `null` values from `count.get`.

Comment: I am not sure this is the intent of the example the OP mentions

Comment: This was just an example code from a tutorial; I didn't have much choice but to use the ArrayList!  This does look much nicer, though.  I'm still a bit confused as to what the count.get(idx)+1 does ---

Comment: @james it just gets the element at index `idx` and add 1 to it -- see my answer

Answer (score 0):

In your specific case, what you are looking for is a *sparse array*. In Java we use a `HashMap<Integer, Integer>` for that purpose. You don't need any initialization with zeros, but you do need to check for `null`:

```
final Integer curr = count.get(idx);
count.put(idx, curr == null? 1 : curr+1);
```

Comment: I'm going to check out the HashMap next; this was just in a tutorial, but I do like how the HashMap stuff works. Neat!

Comment: @james please note that a `HashMap` makes no guarantee as to insertion order; if you want insertion order to be respected, use a `LinkedHashMap`.

Comment: OP would probably be more interested in key sorting for this example.